# Approximate logarithmic bound on expected maximum via central limit theorem

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, asymptotics, gaussian, moments

If $Z_i$ are standard normal, possibly dependent, one can show that
$$E\left[\max_{i=1,...,M} Z_i^2\right]\leq 3\ln M + 1.$$

I'm looking for a similar (asymptotic) bound for asymptotically normal random variables.

Let $X_{i}$ be iid with mean 0 and unit variance. Let $(a_{n,j,i})$ be a triple indexed array of non-negative constants, where $n\in\mathbb{N}, j=1,...M_n$ and $i=1,...n$, for a sequence $M_n$ satisfying $\ln M_n\leq n$. Let $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{n,j,i}^2=1$ for all $n,j$. Then under some appropriate conditions, the central limit theorem implies for $n$ large that
$$Z_{n,j}:= \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n, j, i}X_{i}$$
is approximately standard normal for any $j=1,...M_n$.

I'm looking for conditions under which we have (something like)
$$E\left[\max_{j=1,...,M_n} Z_{n,j}^2\right]\leq A_n\ln M_n + B_n$$
for some (hopefully convergent) sequences $A_n, B_n$ that we can say something about (say, in terms of $n, M_n,$ the $a_{n,j,i}$ and the distribution of $X_i$). Does anyone here perhaps know some related literature on this topic or some simple conditions and arguments to get something of this flavor?

The case that $X_i$ are sub-Gaussian is easy enough, but I'd like to be able to consider a larger family of distributions.

I realize this is not a completely well-defined problem, but I'm hoping it's clear enough what kind of results I'm interested in.